# MySQL LAST_INSERT_ID() returns 0 instead of recently inserted ID

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework

I need to insert values into a table B with the ID generated from table A.
As table A has got primary key which is auto_increment I tried using `select LAST_INSERT_ID()`  to get the id for the recently inserted value. But the LAST_INSERT_ID() returns 0.

This is the Scala function that I'm using to carry out the insertions

```
    def insertNewTagsAndMap(conceptCode : String, questionId : String, tagNames : List[String]) {
    
    for (tagName <- tagNames) {
      DB.withTransaction { implicit conn =>
      val tagInsertionQuery = SQL(""" 
        INSERT INTO tbl_tags(tag_name) values ({tag_name});
      """)
      .on("tag_name"->tagName).executeInsert()
      }
      
      DB.withConnection { implicit conn =>
      val getRecentTagIdQuery = SQL(
        "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as id_for_tag;"
      )

      var tagId = getRecentTagIdQuery().head[Int]("id_for_tag")
      println(tagId.getClass)
      }
      mapTagToQuestion(conceptCode, questionId,  tagId)
    }
}
```

Comment: In most cases this means that there is a lot of queries which are executed by the framework hiddenly between your queries.

Comment: Note that LAST_INSERT_ID() can only return the recent id generated *in the same session*. If your Scala code is running these queries asynchronously, it's probably acquiring a different connection from a connection pool. So they count as different sessions. You have to find a way to execute the query for LAST_INSERT_ID() in the same session. I don't use Scala, so I can't suggest the right way to do this with Scala.

Comment: you can use `getGeneratedKeys` function to obtain generated keys

https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/methods/java.sql.Statement/getGeneratedKeys

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) 0 is returned from `LAST_INSERT_ID()` if connection has not yet performed successful INSERT.

In Scala `withConnection` acquire and closes the connection every time it is called.

It looks like you are using first `withTransaction` and after that `withConnection`. Try to do both operations in one block of code.